# How to solve $2x^5+5\sqrt{2}x^4+20x^3+20\sqrt{2}x^2+20x+4\sqrt{2}=0$?

Tags: polynomials

> How to solve $$2x^5+5\sqrt{2}x^4+20x^3+20\sqrt{2}x^2+20x+4\sqrt{2}=0?$$

I just have no idea and I'have some [knowledge](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:463553%20[polynomials]) about the polynomial equations. Here, just nothing.

Comment: I think the most simple way is to notice that $x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is root. After that you need to divide polynomial to $x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and get the polynomial of 4-th degree. Than you can apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots

Comment: This is so embarrassing :(

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve(2x%5E5%2B5%5Csqrt%7B2%7Dx%5E4%2B20x%5E3%2B20%5Csqrt%7B2%7Dx%5E2%2B20x%2B4%5Csqrt%7B2%7D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $x = \sqrt{2}y$ and divide by $\sqrt{2}^5$. The resulting equation is

$$y^5 + (y+1)^5 = 0.$$

Now substitute $y = -1/(z+1)$ and multiply by $(z+1)^5$ and you get
$$z^5 - 1 = 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

The only real root is
$$
\alpha=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=- 0.707106781187\cdots 
$$

The polynomial divided by $x-\alpha$ then has degree $4$ and has roots $\alpha\pm i\beta$, $\alpha\pm i \gamma$.

Comment: Come on, how can I miss that?

Comment: How can one easily observe that real root?

Comment: @Zacky. With all these powers of $2$ and two occurences of $\sqrt 2$, it looks "natural" (at least to me).

Answer (score 1):

We had one root $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ as already said in answers and comments. After long division remains $$2 x^4+4 \sqrt{2} x^3+16 x^2+12 \sqrt{2} x+8=0$$
Make $x=y-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ to get
$$2 y^4+10 y^2+\frac{5}{2}=0$$ which is a quadratic in $y^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept 3 answers at the question.

Comment: @Aqua. Where is the problem ? But thnks for your comment. Cheers :-)